# Cannot resolve column name among field names

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have created a dataframe as below:

```scala
val bankDF = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").option("delimiter",";").load("/user/pvviswanathan_yahoo_com/Bank_Dataset.csv");

bankDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = ["age";"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"
campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y": string]
```

After that when I tried the below, it is throwing error - Cannot resolve column name "age" among field names

```scala
bankDF.groupBy("age").count().show;

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "age" among ("age";"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan
";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y");
```

Comment: You should use `bankDF.show()` to make sure you read data correctly. As your output in reading step, I think `delimiter` option doesn't work so you read all columns as one

Comment: the problem seems that you have only 1 column of type string which is named `"age";"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan
";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"`, you can check your schema using `df.printSchema`

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly, maybe you work with an unupdated version of bankDF (before delimiter was applied). also make sure you dont use data copied with style from any place (try to select-replace all ; instances with the real ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when tried to work with `CSV` files.

```
      Dataset<Row> students = spark.read().format("csv")
            .option("sep", ";")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load("data/students.csv");
```

Using the advice of  Raphael Roth, I printed the `Students` schema and discovered that indeed Spark considers all the column as one value:

```
 +----------------------+
 |studentId, name, lname|
 +----------------------+
 |      1, Mickey, Mouse|
 |       2, Donald, Duck|
 +----------------------+

root
  |-- studentId, name, lname: string (nullable = true)
```

And the error I got was

> Cannot resolve column name "studentId" among (studentId, name, lname);

So the problem was indeed in the `seperator` character. So i changed

```
 .option("sep", ";")
```

to be

```
 .option("sep", ",")
```

(as indeed the CSV separator is `,`)

And now the schema is correct:

```
root
  |-- studentId: integer (nullable = true)
  |--  name: string (nullable = true)
  |--  lname: string (nullable = true)
```