# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve column

Tags: java, apache-spark, filter

I have the following dataframe :

```
+-------------+
|limit_speed  |
+-------------+
|30           |
|40           |
+-------------+
```

I did the following code :

```
Dataset<Row> data = df.withColumn("vtmp",lit(40));
```

I get the following dataframe :

```
+---------------+--------------+
|limit_speed    |vtmp          |
+---------------+--------------+
|30             |40            |
|40             |40            |
+---------------+--------------+
```

When I tried the following code :

```
data.filter(col("vtmp").gt(col("limit_speed")));
```

I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`vtmp`' given input columns:.........
```

Thank you

Comment: May be you should add backticks to vtmp while adding the column. Check out these issues they may help! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905031/cannot-resolve-column-name-among-field-names https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698322/cannot-resolve-column-numeric-column-name-in-spark-dataframe/42698510

Comment: Try qualifying it `data.filter(data.col("vtmp")...`